# Prompt installation folder dialog conditionally

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project, custom-action

I have created a setup project in visual studio 2008. I want to prompt installation folder dialog conditionally.

1. I have a dialog box with two radio buttons.
2. If user selects radio button '1' i.e. Standard installation then installation process should start directly.
3. But if user selects radio button '2' i.e. Custom installation then installation folder dialog should be presented to user and once user selects installation folder then installation should start.
4. I have written custom action dll in c++ which retrieves the radio button values and then do the required action depending upon the value.

But I don't know what is the command to show a dialog from custom action. Is there any command like 'dialog.show' that I can use? I searched online also but NO luck. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard WinAPI function:

```
MessageBox(hParent, "Dialog Message", "Dialog Caption", MB_OK);
```

or even call a "YES/NO" dialog:

```
if ( IDYES == MessageBox(hParent, "Continue installation process?", 
     "Database connection stablishing error", MB_YESNO )
{ ... }
```

If you once decide to use a C# instead C++, it would be quite easy to even import some custom-defined winforms this way, as far as I know.

Best wishes!